# How to edit google chrome inner CSS or JS files (source code)?

Tags: css, google-chrome

As we know, all menus and settings in Chrome are managing by CSS files and javascripts.
Is it possible to edit this CSS files or/and JS to manage menus/settings etc.?

For example chrome://settings/options_bundle.js  or chrome://resources/css/button.css
Is it possible to change these files in some way?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for doing it.
First way is simple, but slow:

1. Download sources (it will be Chromium, not Chrome) (http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium/src.git)
2. edit some file (ex. http://git.chromium.org/gitweb/?p=chromium/src.git;a=blob;f=chrome/browser/resources/options/browser_options.js;h=548a6068d4007f25427caf70b04c26575dafbc3d;hb=HEAD)
3. compile `packed_resources` and `packed_extra_resources` targets, place newly created `resources.pak` and `chrome.pak` files in the appropriate place.

Another way is some kind of a cheat:

1. find `resources.pak` file in the install dir. All of resources, that Chrome uses are placed in this file. It is like an archive without compression.
2. Edit this file. But the length of your changes must remain exactly the same as the length of original text. For example:

   ```
   Before:
   {
   color: red;
   }
   (length: 15)

   After:
   {color: green;}
   (length: 15)
   ```

You can overcome this limitation by deeper understanding of pak file format (which is described well https://code.google.com/p/grit-i18n/source/browse/trunk/grit/format/data_pack.py?r=79)

[image: Here is a result]